# R shiny error while rendering textinput for DT output

Tags: r, shiny, dt, textinput

I am having some really strange issue when rendering a textinput for DT in my shiny application. The textinput stores some value that is used as one of the settings of the application. These settings are stored in a reactive list, one list member is a data.table - that stores all the settings for rendering.

I made a reproducible example instead of code snippets. Not pretty, but it illustrates.

```
library(shiny)

rv = reactiveValues()


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

      textInput(inputId = "textinput", label = h3("Numeric input"), value = "some value"),
      tags$hr(),
      fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("textinput"))),
      tags$hr(),
      tabPanel("Settings table for viewing", dataTableOutput('settings_table')),

))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({

    # lst_names = list()
    # lst_values = list()


    rv$textinput <-  renderText( input$textinput )
    output$textinput <- renderText({ input$textinput }) # this is displayed nicely

    # lst_names = c(lst_names, "rv$textinput") 
    # lst_values = c(lst_values, rv$textinput)        


    rv$settings = data.table(Var_names = "rv$textinput", Var_values = rv$textinput)

    })

  output$settings_table = DT::renderDataTable(options = list(pageLength = 50), {
    rv$settings
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I found this chunk of text in the github of DT, but I cannot figure out a way to make it work.
Same issue with numericinput, rendertext, renderprint, moving rendertext/print out of the "observe" chunk.

Any suggestions?

Comment: it would be easier to help you with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: why is `"rv$textinput"` in quotes ?

Comment: @bretauv: Added. Pork Chop: it is the name of the setting that has the value next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the good `dataTableOutput`. You have to use `DT::dataTableOutput` or, equivalently, `DT::DTOutput`.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  textInput(inputId = "textinput", label = h3("Numeric input"), 
            value = "some value"),
  tags$hr(),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("textinput"))),
  tags$hr(),
  tabPanel("Settings table for viewing", DTOutput('settings_table')),

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$textinput <- renderText({ input$textinput }) 

  rv <- reactiveValues()

  observe({

    rv$textinput <- input$textinput

    rv$settings <- data.frame(
      Var_names = "rv$textinput", 
      Var_values = rv$textinput
    )

  })

  output$settings_table <- renderDT(options = list(pageLength = 50), {
    rv$settings
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```